# Connecting USB HDD

Tags: windows, usb-storage

Suddenly I found I can't connect any external drive by using USB adapter. I have three different adapters but none is detected in my Windows 10. If I connect them to my other  Windows 11 machine they detected fine. How to solve this problem?

Windows 10 computer management console:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps your USB controller is glitching. Shutdown the computer, disconnect the power (pull the plug), press the power button for 30 seconds, then reboot.